Access denied when trying to access Q: in Microsoft APP-V on the client computer even as an administrator
access denied
I have an application virtualized with APP-V Microsoft and I need to rescue some files including the executable.
Due to a big problem I only have 2 copies on the client computer.
Virtualized with Microsoft APP-V on the Q:\ drive, where access is denied.
I remember that many years ago, using commands in CMD (if I'm not mistaken), I was able to open and access the contents of that partition.
I ask for help to achieve this, as I have not been successful in researching.
I expected to have read and write access to the Q:\ drive.
Tried, takeown, chkdsk and others.
